# Finite sum involving trigonometric functions

Tags: summation, physics, greens-function

The temperature Green's function in *momentum*-frequency representation of a system of free phonons (in one-dimension) is given by [1]:

\begin{equation}
D^{(0)}(k_n,\omega_{n'}) = -m\frac{\omega_{k_n}^2}{\omega_{n'}^2+\omega_{k_n}^2},
\end{equation}
where $\omega_k$ is the phonon dispersion,
\begin{equation}
\omega_{k_n}^2 = 4\frac{\kappa}{m}\sin^2\frac{k_n}{2}.
\end{equation}
In the context of calculating the temperature Green's function for a toy (interacting) problem, I need the full perturbation series for the exact Green's function in *position*-frequency space. I therefore have to compute discrete inverse Fourier transforms which amount to finite sums of the following form:

\begin{eqnarray}
D^{(0)}_{j0}(\omega_{n'}) &=& -m\sum_{k_n=0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin^2\frac{k_n}{2}}{a^2+\sin^2\frac{k_n}{2}}e^{ik_nj} \\
&=& -m\sum_{n=0}^{N/2} \frac{\sin^2\frac{n\pi}{N}}{a^2+\sin^2\frac{n\pi}{N}}e^{i \frac{2\pi n}{N} j},
\end{eqnarray}
where $k_n=\frac{2\pi n}{N}$ with $0\le n\le N/2$, and $j$ is the position coordinate (the model is on a lattice so this labels the site), and $a$ is a constant. $N$ is even.

Any advice on the possibility of computing the sums of the type above would be greatly appreciated!

[1] *Abrikosov, A. A.; Gorkov, L. P.; Dzyaloshinski, I. E.*, Methods of quantum field theory in statistical physics, Englewood Cliffs, N.J.: Prentice-Hall, Inc. XV, 352 p. (1963). [ZBL0135.45003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0135.45003).:

Comment: Where is $k_{n}$ in your formula?

Comment: Post edited: hopefully it is now more clear.

Comment: I would say a closed form is not available here... Since the sums are finite, why not just compute them as given?

Comment: Though maybe it's better to use fast fourier transform algorithms when the number $N$ is large

Comment: I would like to keep things on paper as far as possible, since I intend to find the function:
\begin{equation}
D_{jl}(\omega_n) = \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\left(2\lambda T\right)^s D_{j0}^{(0)}(\omega_n)\left[D_{00}^{(0)}(\omega_n)\right]^{s-1}D_{0l}^{(0)}(\omega_n),
\end{equation}
since the poles of the above should reveal the energies of the eigenstates of the system. As far as I know, the solubility of the problem should not rely on $N$ being large.